# Using the NetSuite 'N/ui/dialog' Module in Client Functions that Return a Boolean

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

So, the 'N/ui/dialog' module in SuiteScript 2.x gives nicer looking versions of the native JavaScript `alert()` and `confirm()` functions that match the UI theme. However, when using them in the client functions like `validateField()` and `onSave()` they don't pause the script execution, so if you need to return a false to do something like preventing the record from saving, it doesn't work. In fact, I believe that if you try to return false from the dialog's promise object, the function won't even see it anyway.

Now, I've seen some ways to make it work in `onSave()`, but those methods don't appear to work in a scripted form due to some NS-provided values not existing in a scripted form. Also, none of these methods account for trying to use a dialog in something like the `validateField()` function. When using `dialog.alert()`, this isn't really an issue as a false can be returned after creating the alert regardless of the alert's promise. For example:

```
const onSave = (context) => {
    let currRec = context.currentRecord,
        a = Number(currRec.getValue({ fieldId : "custpage_first_number" })),
        b = Number(currRec.getValue({ fieldId : "custpage_second_number" }));
    
    if (a < b) {
        dialog.alert({
                title : "Dialog Title"
            ,   message : "The first number is less than the second number"
        })
            .then(result => {
                console.log(result);
            });
        return false;
    }
    
    return true;
};
```

Doesn't really work for `dialog.confirm()`, though. Is there any way to get it to work in these client trigger functions?

Answer (score 0):

the `N/dialog` method's return type is [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) . Meaning if you return it from a method you are not returning boolean.  Some entry points accept being assigned as async but i don't think that it's officially supported -- maybe not even 2.1 on the client actually.

To make matters worse...in your example the onSave has returned BEFORE the alert even comes up -- that's a features of promises not a bug.

however, You could:

- track the work you wanted to do ( in this case the condition)
- ALWAYS return false
- fire dialog.alert
- in the `then` if value is true then you could repeat the work... i.e. do the save. If the value is false then you've already killed the save.

You'll have to leave a hint somewhere so that whenif the dialog retriggers a save it is exempted from the combo of:

1. triggering the dialog again
2. and forcing false to be returned.

You can leave this hint as a scoped variable.

example:

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.1
 * @NModuleScope Public
 * @NScriptType ClientScript
 */

define(['N/ui/dialog'], Ndialog=>{
  const conditionsToCheck = { };
  const isClearOfConditions = ()=> Object.values(conditionsToCheck).filter(f=>typeof f === 'function').length === 0;

  // noop right now
  const somethingThatTriggersSave = ()=>undefined;
  return {
    saveRecord :  ()=>{
      let a = 0,b=1;
      if( conditionsToCheck['trythis'] !== 'resolved' ){
        conditionsToCheck['trythis'] =  ()=>( a < b );
      }

      if( !isClearOfConditions()){
      // call this BEFORE returning
      Promise.all(
        Object.entries(conditionsToCheck)
          .filter(([name,f])=>typeof f === 'function')
          .map(( [name,fn])=>Promise.resolve([ name , fn()]))
      ).then(results =>Promise.all(results.map(([name,condition],i)=> {
        const next = condition === true ? Ndialog.confirm({title: `${name} failed`, message: 'you ok with this?'}) : Promise.resolve(true);
        return next.then(answer => {
          if (answer === true) conditionsToCheck[name] = 'resolved';
          // do your save here
        });
      })))
        .then(somethingThatTriggersSave)
        .catch(console.error);

      // fail if there are still functions to check
      return false
      }
      return true;

    }
  }
});
```